# Uploading GPX file to website and displaying it visually

Tags: leaflet, javascript, gpx

I'd like to create a file upload button and then print the resulting gpx file on the map, could anyone have a look at this code to see where I'm going wrong?

body:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Select a file: <input type="file" id="uploadID"><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
```

js:

```js
let gpx = document.getElementById('uploadID');
gpx.onchange = function() {
  new L.GPX(gpx, {
    async: true, marker_options: {
      startIconUrl: 'pin-icon-start.png',
      endIconUrl: 'pin-icon-end.png',
      shadowUrl: 'pin-shadow.png'
    }
  }).on('loaded', function(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
  }).addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: body: <form action="/action_page.php">
  Select a file: <input type="file" id="uploadID"><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

Comment: It might help if you edit your question and tell us what exactly is not working right now. Also, it looks like you're already using some mapping or gpx libraries, but which?